# Changing background in PyQt5 on selecting another widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, qt5

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

def foo():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    window.setStyleSheet("""
        background-color: green;
        """)
    btn1 = QPushButton('My_Button', window)
    btn1.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton{
                background-color:yellow;
            }
        """)
    btn1.setGeometry(25,25,50,50)
    window.resize(100,100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```

How Can we change background color of main widget(QWidget).
Example :- when we press **TAB** , My_Button is selected so what i want is when we select any widget so it can change contents(here background) of another widgets.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding: you want to change a color of a widget when a widget that is on another window gets focused? And what if there are more than two buttons, and maybe they are even on their own different window? It might help to understand what would be the purpose of this, so that we could better understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a child class My_Button inheriting from the QPushButton,and override its focusInEvent event listener - in your case, run the lines to change the color of your main widget background. Then, use this child class in your application.